# Reference two separate tables in same ListView to populate table

Tags: asp.net, listviewitem

Is it possible to reference two separate tables, say - JourneyStatistics (JS) and Journeys (J) ?

Under the Autom8 Rider column, I want to populate those rows with the username value in our Journeys database table, whilst all others are going to use the JourneyStatistics database table.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Autom8 Rider</th>
            <th>Total Carpool Miles</th>
            <th>As Driver</th>
            <th>As Passenger</th>
            <th>Total Savings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <asp:ListView ID="leaderboardList" runat="server"
        ItemType="SE_TeamZephyr.Models.JourneyStatistics" SelectMethod="GetJourneyStatistics">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <%-- Currently adds in a line under rank number --%>
                    <td><%#: Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></td>
                    <td><%#:Item.JourneyStatisticsID%></td>
                    <td><%#:Item.TotalDistanceTravelled%></td>
                    <td><%#:Item.DistanceAsDriver%></td>
                    <td><%#:Item.DistanceAsPassenger%></td>
                    <td><%#:Item.FuelCost%></td>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
</table>
```

The above works, but that's because it's only using one table. Cheers.

Comment: Have you heard of Joins? In your query use join to get data from both tables if you have proper relationships created.

Comment: You should really separate out your data layer from your presentation layer. Figure out what the needs are in the presentation layer and then work backwards. Using keys you can join data but the presentation layer should not be concerned with such details, this is a business layer or data-access layer detail.